# Is there a way to delete Azure Function from my Function App using C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to delete an Azure function from my Function App through C#.
But while deleting it programmatically, the function is not seen on the User Interface, but when I check it through Advanced tools (Kudu), I can still see my Azure function.

So basically while deleting the Azure function, what I do is, I delete it's function.json, and by doing so the Azure function isn't visible in Functions App list (see image below)

[image]

But when I go to Advanced Kudu to check whether it has been deleted, I can still see it, but without the function.json file. I had done this before (around 6 months back) and back then it was working properly. I don't know if I am doing it wrong or has anything changed.

[image]

Any help with the code would be appreciated.

Thanks

Edit:

The details that I have with me is the Function App's username, password, url, name (**https://my-function-app.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot**), and azure function's name.

A little sample code of what I did which worked 6 months back

```
private WebClient _webClient = new WebClient
        {
            Headers = { ["ContentType"] = "application/json" },               
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password),
            BaseAddress = functionsSiteRoot,
        };

var functionJson =
          JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FunctionSettings>(_webClient.DownloadString("MyFunctionName/function.json"));            

        _webClient.Headers["If-Match"] = "*";
        _webClient.UploadString("MyFunctionName/function.json", "DELETE", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(functionJson));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use REST API to perform this operation.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/functions/{functionName}?api-version=2016-08-01
```

**Method:** `DELETE`

**Code Snippet:**

```cs
 HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, string.Format("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/functions/{functionName}?api-version=2016-08-01", "Pass All Param In {}")));

 request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", results.access_token);

 HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
 {
    dynamic objApiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

 }
 else
 {
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Sorry Invalid Request");
 }
```

For details please have a look on [official docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft0BK.png)

**Note:** For token request your `resource/Scope` should be `https://management.azure.com`. Pass your token while send request.

**Update:**

You can request for token  using `client_credentials` authentication flow. Try below format:

**Azure Portal Credentials For App Id and Tenant Id:**

[image]

**Application Secret from Portal:**

[image]

**Token Endpoint Or URL:**

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenantName.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token
```

**Request Param:**

```
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:b603c7be_Your_App_ID_e6921e61f925
client_secret:Vxf1Sl_Your_App_Secret_2XDSeZ8wL/Yp8ns4sc=
resource:https://graph.microsoft.com
```

**PostMan Sample:**

[image]

**Token On Response:**

[image]

**Code Snippet For Token:**

```
            //Token Request End Point
            string tokenUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant/oauth2/token";
            var tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl);

            //I am Using client_credentials as It is mostly recomended
            tokenRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["grant_type"] = "client_credentials",
                ["client_id"] = "20e08e95-_Your_App_ID_e9c711b0d19e",
                ["client_secret"] = "+trl[ZFl7l_Your_App_Secret__ghon9",
                ["resource"] = "https://management.azure.com/"
            });

            dynamic json;
            AccessTokenClass results = new AccessTokenClass();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            var tokenResponse = await client.SendAsync(tokenRequest);

            json = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenClass>(json);


            //New Block For Accessing Data from API
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, string.Format("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/YOurSubscription/resourceGroups/YourResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/DeleteTestFuncAppName/functions/DeleteFunctionNameThatYouWantToDelete?api-version=2016-08-01"));
            //Passing Token For this Request
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", results.access_token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            //Read Server Response
            dynamic objServerResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

**Class I Have Used:**

```
   public class AccessTokenClass
        {
            public string token_type { get; set; }
            public string expires_in { get; set; }
            public string resource { get; set; }
            public string scope { get; set; }
            public string access_token { get; set; }
            public string refresh_token { get; set; }

        }
```

**Point To Remember:**

If you got this error

> InvalidAuthenticationToken: The received access token is not valid: at
>   least one of the claims 'puid' or 'altsecid' or 'oid' should be
>   present. If you are accessing as application please make sure service
>   principal is properly created in the tenant

You have to assign role to your application like below:

[image]

Comment: Hi Farid
I edited my original question. Kindly take a look.

Comment: Farid, can you please provide me a sample code of how to get the tokens?

Comment: Sure, I have already updated my answer please take a look and let me know if you need any more assistance Thanks.

Comment: Farid, Thanks a lot for the code snippet. When I executed the above code, I am getting the below error


{code": "AuthorizationFailed",
"message": "The client 'someclientid' with object id 'someobjectid' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/delete' over scope '/subscriptions/subscriptionvalue/resourceGroups/resourcegroupname/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/FunctionAppName/functions/FunctionName' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}

What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: Farid, when I delete the functions manually, it is allowing me to delete it, but not allowing to delete the same programmatically.

Comment: Deleting manually and programmatically is not same. Your application should have service principle role. See my screen shot and assign owner role to your application.

Comment: I already did that before performing the deletion through code.
Screen shot [link](https://imgur.com/a/9z40p6h)

What else am I missing?

Comment: Would you kindly try [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/deletefunction#code-try-0) if works then your token has no permission. Check it.

Comment: Yeah, it worked from the link that you provided. I did gave permission to my app but still the deletion isn't working. How do I check if the given permission has been applied correctly?

Comment: Best approach will be create a new app and just replace the tenantId, clientId and clientSecret to my code sample. assign application role on it from IAM then try. My answer is correct and tested.

Comment: Yes, it did. Thanks a lot. And FYI, I also made the old way work by tweaking my old code. So now, both the ways are working for me. 

Thanks a ton, mate. :)

Comment: Good to hear. Happy coding. Where was the deadlock?

Comment: As you said, it was permission issue. I was using client id, and client secret which was not granted permission. So I created a new app, and executed the above and it worked like a charm. Thanks again.